Display glitches and "shakes" back and forth sometimes
A few months ago now, a problem started happening where my entire display appears to "shake" off the screen center and back extremely fast, with graphical glitches appearing as well. This cannot be picked up by recording the screen. I have taken a video on my phone to illustrate the problem:

here it is in better resolution: https://files.catbox.moe/s1vw7r.webm
It seems to happen most often when these conditions are met:
-RAM is at least half full
-CPU is undergoing heavy usage
-PC has been on for a long time (> a day)
-I'm entering fullscreen on some application
I've discovered that I can sometimes make the problem go away by locking the screen (Super+L). Restarting the PC always "fixes" it, until it happens again.
I'm not a dev, but my theory is that this is related to either GDM, the gnome shell, or my swap partition (I have swap set on my main SSD drive). This started happening a few months ago but I would just deal with it. In the above video, I was playing the video game SOMA and it just started happening in the middle of it; when I was entering a new area and the CPU/RAM had to work a little more. It seems to happen more often on Linux-native games, but it also happens if I try to full screen a playing video sometimes, especially if my RAM is close to being full/high CPU process is happening in the background.
Specs:
-Ubuntu 22.04 with Mutter (Wayland)
-6.5.0-28-lowlatency kernel (and it's been happening for quite a few kernels before that)
-GNOME 42.9
-Dash to Panel extension for GNOME
-Samsung UJ59 32" 4K monitor set to 60Hz
-AMD RX 5500 GPU with OpenGL and Vulkan drivers from AMD
-AMD Ryzen 3 5300G CPU
-16.1 GB RAM
-17.2 GB swap partition on my boot drive (Samsung EVO 970 SSD)
